# Javascript create an object, keyed by array value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I have a method which needs to return a user object from a supplied `id` parameter. Further methods will use this structure so it's not a simple case of using the existing structure.

Essentially I have a database which contains a `type` key, this is filtered so that I have a collection of `users`. What I need to do is create an object which is keyed by the users `_id` value and contains the users object with the `_id` and `type` omitted.

Using lodash or some ES6 sugar I would like to transform the following `Array`;

```
[
  {
    "_id": "0e12e661cb50068a135b36067f001d20",
    "name": "Joe Bloggs",
    "type": "user"
  },
  {
    "_id": "0e12e661cb50068a135b36067f00373f",
    "name": "Ben Bloggs",
    "type": "user"
  }
]
```

Into the following `Object`, with the `_id` and `type` omitted;

```
{
  "0e12e661cb50068a135b36067f001d20": {
    "name": "Joe Bloggs"
  },
  "0e12e661cb50068a135b36067f00373f": {
    "name": "Ben Bloggs"
  }
}
```

**EDIT** I need to return the object and NOT the name as further properties could be added to these objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with just `reduce()`.

```js
var data = [{
  "_id": "0e12e661cb50068a135b36067f001d20",
  "name": "Joe Bloggs",
  "type": "user"
}, {
  "_id": "0e12e661cb50068a135b36067f00373f",
  "name": "Ben Bloggs",
  "type": "user"
}]

var result = data.reduce(function(r, e) {
  r[e._id] = {name: e.name};
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

ES6 version with arrow function

```
var result = data.reduce((r, e) => (r[e._id] = {name: e.name}, r), {})
```

Update: To just exclude specific properties from new object you can use `Object.assign()` [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1465/) to create copy of object and then `delete` to delete some properties or you can use `forEach()` loop and add properties that you want [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1464/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, please see my **EDIT** on the question. I need the object with the `_id` and `type` properties omitted and NOT just the name property. At some stage, the user object may have additional properties added which would break this.

Comment: In that case you can use something like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1462/ or this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1464/

Comment: That's bloody awesome, please put one of those up and I will gladly accept. Thank you :-)

Comment: I updated my answer, note that if you want to use `Object.assign` version it only works for shallow copy of objects so if you have `{key: {key: value}}` it wont work.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up :-)